# What's with the winter bash people all in a heart shape?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015

I just thought it interesting that all the little winter bash people were all sitting in a heart shape:

[image]

Is it secret message that has to do with Valentines day, the devs having fun, or did it happen by sheer random chance?

Comment: We're all about love.

Comment: I'm staring at these little guys for 5 minutes, didn't see any heart yet. My friend saw me staring at them and now because of you he thinks I'm freak.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, try letting them sit for a *loooong* time. I think I had the page open for 45min - 1hour or more, *only then* did they get tired of snowball fights and sat down.

Comment: @CalebKleveter If you wait more, they'll get hit by the train.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, are you joking?

Comment: @CalebKleveter Yes, unfortunately :(

Comment: Yes, it's a secret message that has to do with Valentines day, because that's two months away **ಠ_ಠ**

Comment: I've refreshed the [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/) page about 100 times and have not seen them form a heart. Zero love...

Comment: @DanielStorm maybe that's your problem...

Comment: I've come across this twice. Do they gather after you get a hat and visit the Winter Bash page or something?

Comment: All I need is [3 more down-votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats/270794#270993)!

Comment: I've had the page open for almost 6 hours and the little guys are still slinging snowballs at each other. One of them even tossed a snowball straight up and hit himself in the face. No heart though :(

Comment: So I left the page open for a total of 8 hours again yesterday, and they finally formed a heart. I opened the page again today (it's relaxing to watch the little stick guys throw snowballs at each other), and they made a heart in about an hour. Perhaps it's a random amount of time?